# How do I change the opening and closing tag highlighting in Sublime Text so it's much more obvious?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext

The highlighting of opening and closing tags in Sublime Text is very subtle and hard to see. When you click an a tag, for example, a  tag, it will underline the div tag and it's closing  tag with a faint dotted underline. I like how Notepad++ does it--really bright and obvious. I've been unable to find anywhere I can change the way this displays. I am using Sublime Text 2 with Emmit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter), specifically [Configuring Highlight Style](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter#configuring-highlight-style).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link is a plugin for the editor. While I understand link only answers can become invalid, this solution relies on the plugin. Giving a full description of all of the details of the plugin, in my opinion, seems redundant. If the plugin is no longer valid, this answer also, becomes invalid. Of course, if you have a better practice, please let me know, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: This would be a good answer for people using pure HTML.  BracketHighlighter does NOT work with React JSX (as of 2019).  so it will highlight plenty of cool things, but not your html (jsx) matching tags.  You'll need to leave the sublime default matcher on for that.  which, is not as nice, and hard to see.

Comment: Plugin seems to be failing on a basic html files, trying to match `select` tags